# Typing a dynamically assigned attribute

Tags: python, plugins, type-hinting, python-typing, setattr

I am writing a "plugin" for an existing python package and wondering how I would properly type-hint something like this.

### Scenario

A python object from a framework I am working with has a `plugins` attribute that is designed to be extended by user-created plugins. For instance: (very simplified)

```py
# External module that I have no control over

from typing import Any

class BaseClassPluginsCollection:
    ...

class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr_a = 'a'
        self.plugins = BaseClassPluginsCollection()

    def add_plugin(self, plugin: Any, plugin_name: str):
        setattr(self.plugins, plugin_name, plugin)
```

So the `plugins` attribute is basically an empty object which users (like myself) will add new plugin objects to. So in my case, I might do something like this:

```py
class MyCustomPlugin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_attr_a = "my attribute"

my_plugin = MyCustomPlugin()
base_object = BaseClass()
base_object.add_plugin(my_plugin, "my_plugin")
```

In practice, this all works fine and I can add and then use the plugin during program execution without issue. However, I would like to properly type-hint this so that my IDE knows about the plugin. Is such a thing even possible?

Currently (using VS Code) I get the red squiggly line when I try and reference my plugin, even though it *does* work fine during execution.

For instance, if I try and use the `base_object` created above, I get an error from the static type checker:

```
print(f"{base_object.plugins.my_plugin.my_attr_a=}")
```

[image: screen-shot of VSCode type error]

What would be the appropriate way to handle this type of scenario? Is there a method for type-hinting something of this sort when its being added during execution using `setattr()`? Should I be doing some sort if aliasing before trying to access `my_plugin`?

Comment: To be clear, `BaseClass` is defined in a _foreign_ module that you have no control over, right? So you just want your own code that comes after the `.add_plugin` call to be annotated in a way that allows static type checkers to infer the type of `base_object.plugins.my_plugin` correctly, i.e. to be `MyCustomPlugin`. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Hi @DaniilFajnberg, yes you are correct: in example shown above `BaseClass` is part of the framework I am building the plugin for, and it's implementation is not something I control. And yes: the ideal solution would be for a static type checker to recognize my `base_object.plugins.my_plugin` attribute as a valid attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid you are out of luck, if you are looking for some magical elegant annotation.

### Dynamic attribute assignment

The problem lies in the way that the the package you are using (the one defining `BaseClass`) is designed. Adding a new attribute to an object using `setattr` means you are **dynamically** altering the interface of that object. A **static** type checker will never be able to pick that up. Even in the simplest case, you will run into errors:

```py
class Foo:
    pass

class Bar:
    pass

f = Foo()
setattr(f, "bar", Bar())
print(type(f.bar))
```

Even though the output `<class '__main__.Bar'>` is as expected, `mypy` immediately complains:

```
error: "Foo" has no attribute "bar"  [attr-defined]
```

You might think this is trivial, but consider the situation if the new attribute's name was also dynamically generated by some function `func`:

```py
setattr(f, func(), Bar())
```

Now the only way for a type checker to know what even the name of the attribute is supposed to be, is to execute `foo`.

> Static type checkers don't execute your code, they just read it.

So to come back to your code example, there is no way to infer the type of the attribute `base_object.plugins.my_plugin` because that attribute is set dynamically.

### Workaround

What you can always do however is just assure the type checker that `my_plugin` is in fact of the type you expect it to be. To do that however, you first need to tell the type checker that `base_object.plugins` even *has* such an attribute. For that I see no way around subclassing and just declaring that attribute:

```py
class CustomPluginsCollection(BaseClassPluginsCollection):
    my_plugin: MyCustomPlugin


class SubClass(BaseClass):
    plugins: CustomPluginsCollection
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.plugins = CustomPluginsCollection()

my_plugin = MyCustomPlugin()
base_object = SubClass()
base_object.add_plugin(my_plugin, "my_plugin")
print(f"{base_object.plugins.my_plugin.my_attr_a=}")
```

Now there should be no errors by type checkers and a decent IDE should give you all the type hints for `.my_plugin`.

Whether or not this is doable in practice depends of course on the details of that framework you are using. It may not be trivial to subclass and (re-)declare the attributes as I did here.

---

As a side note, this is why extensible libraries should try to go the inheritance route, allowing you to subclass their own classes and thus define your own interface. But I don't know enough about the package in question to judge here.